# tcp retransmists without connection establishment(syn, syn ack , ack) after a reset packet

Tags: tcp

****Tcp retransmists without connection establishment(syn, syn ack , ack) after a reset packet****

I observed while using a application , i got a reset(RST,ACK)packet. I know that reset packet sent doesnot mean to close the connection but to retry the connection again. 
But why the tcp connection which tried to retransmit packets again has no syn , synack and ack ?

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken. RST means 'connection reset', usually that from the point of view of the sender the connection no longer exists, or never did. In the context of the connection handshake is is emitted by Windows platforms when the backlog queue is full, and in *that* context it is interpreted by Windows clients as 'retry the connection'. But in any case there *is* no connection, so there is no SYN or ACK.